# Typo3 customize footer-menu

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a site on TYPO3 version 8.7.10, I have such a link http://p448297.webspaceconfig.de/footernavigation/allgemein/impressum.html
I need to remove it from footernavigation, how to do it? Thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the properties of your *footernavigation* page and enable the option **Exclude from speaking URL**.

This instructs RealURL to to not add a path segment for this page if it is in the middle of other path segments. If you directly open the page, the page will be part of the path of course, otherwise it would be inaccessible.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me

Answer (score 0):

In the pagesettings for the "footernavigation" page / pagetree node (page,shortcut) just check the "exclude from spealing url" check

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot. I recently started working on typo3

Answer (score 0):

realUrl Provide pretty nice option to exclude a page from URL segment. For that go to Page-> property->General. You will find an option Exclude from speaking URL check this Screenshot.

In your case go to footernavigation separator edit property and exclude this from URL.

```
-root
--Home
--about
--footernavigation // Exclude from realUrl from page property
-- allgemeinx
```

That's it, this what you're actually looking for!

Greetings!

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me